# Sorting a list of points to match an other list to create straight lines without any intersection

Tags: python, arraylist, coordinate-systems

I write code in Python.
I have two lists containing points on a plane: `points1` and `points2`.

Given:
`len(points1) == len(points2)`
Another fact is that all the points in the list `points1` are on one side and all the points in the list `points2` are on the other side, which means that:

```
for p1 of points1:
    for p2 of points2:
        p1.X < p2.X # always true or always false
```

Another fact is that all the points in `points2` are below each other so that:

```
for i of range(len(points2)-1):
    points2[i].X == points2[i+1].X # always true
```

Another fact is that the steps between the points in `points2` are equal. I mean:

```
for i of range(len(points2)-2):
    points2[i+1].Y - points2[i].Y == points2[i+2].Y - points2[i+1].Y # always true
```

[In the picture is a visual example, that the lists is: `points1=[D,E,F], points2=[A,B,C]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkiCV.png)
[image: pic]

I need to build a function that will rearrange the order of the points so that when I create straight lines from the lists as follows:

```
line0 = Line(points1[0], points2[0])
line1 = Line(points1[1], points2[1])
line2 = Line(points1[2], points2[2])
```

and so on, there will be no line that intersects another line.
The `Line` function is an existing function that accepts two points and returns the straight line connecting them.

Do not change the points in the list, but only the order of the list.

I already have a function that accepts 2 straight lines and returns `True` if they intersect and `False` if they don't, called: `isIntersect(line1, line2)`, and i can use it.

Comment: maybe I am missing something, but if you sort the two lists of points based on Y value, you can create lines starting from the smallest y value for every list and then go on

Comment: What you probably missed is that the points in `points1` can be in different positions on the X-axis.

Comment: I changed the image to another example so that it can be seen that your suggestion does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God, here is a solution that works:

```
def sortPoints(points1, points2):
    limit = 1000000
    rounds = 0
    i = 0
    while(i < len(points1) - 1):
        if rounds > limit:
            alert("Could not sort the points to be without intersections.")
            break

        line1 = Line.CreateBound(points1[i], points2[i])
        line2 = Line.CreateBound(points1[i + 1], points2[i + 1])
        if isIntersect(line1, line2):
            points1[i], points1[i + 1] = points1[i + 1], points1[i]
            i = 0
            rounds += 1
            continue

        i += 1
        rounds += 1

    for j in range(len(points1)):
            for k in range(j):
                if j != k:
                    line1 = Line.CreateBound(points1[j], points2[j])
                    line2 = Line.CreateBound(points1[k], points2[k])
                    if isIntersect(line1, line2):
                        points1[i], points1[j] = points1[j], points1[i]
```